# Azure - prediction over time

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, predictive

I am currently studying machine learning and predictive analysis so thought a good way to start would be using Azure ML Studio.
I did the Car Price Tutorial quite successfully however I now want to do something different.
I thought about using Currency Data; Price and Volume to try and predict the price the next day.
Everything has gone smoothly as I copied the Car Price tutorial. However when I come to test it the test wants all the variables to predict the new price, but I don't have any of "tomorrows" data. All I want to do is type tomorrows date and it will predict the price using yesterdays and before price and volume data.
Could you help me please? I am sure it is a small amendment but not sure what!
Thank you
Sam

Answer (score 0):

Great question -- this concept also took some time for me to wrap my head around.

Check out [this great notebook](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/automated-machine-learning/forecasting-forecast-function/auto-ml-forecasting-function.ipynb) all about the `.forecast()` method.

Comment: np. @sabina-cartacio should be able to help with any other questions you may have

Comment: Thanks very much. I deployed my work, I need to set up Power BI now! Thanks again, really appreciate the quick reply! Sam